# How can I run more complex job dependencies via Rundeck

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux, rundeck

I'm currently testing Rundeck for some PoCs I'm working on.
I currently only have it running on a single machine via docker, so I don't have access to multiple nodes.

I want to simulate the following job dependencies:

JobA is needed for JobB and JobC. But JobB and JobC **must** run in parallel.

JobC **must** run if the current local time is 9:00am. Doesn't matter if Job A is finished/started yet or not.

All this should be able to easily scale and expand up to several hundreds of Jobs.

Can some of you guys possibly help me?
I have tried several configurations including the Plug-in Job State. I somehow can't get this to work. The best I can  do is run all the jobs either sequential or parallel.

Answer (score 0):

The best (and easiest) way to achieve that is to use the [ruleset strategy](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/workflow-strategies/ruleset.html#ruleset-workflow-strategy-plugin)  (only available on PagerDuty Process Automation On Prem, formerly "Rundeck Enterprise") calling your jobs using the [job reference step](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/node-steps/builtin.html#job-reference-step).

So, on the community version, the "workaround" is to call the jobs from a Parent Job via [Rundeck API](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/api/rundeck-api.html#running-a-job), which basically is about scripting the custom workflow behavior, [e.g](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/creating-jobs.html#importing-job-definitions):

JobA

```yaml
- defaultTab: nodes
  description: ''
  executionEnabled: true
  id: b156b3ed-fde6-4fdc-af81-1ee919edc4ff
  loglevel: INFO
  name: JobA
  nodeFilterEditable: false
  plugins:
    ExecutionLifecycle: null
  scheduleEnabled: true
  sequence:
    commands:
    - exec: whoami
    keepgoing: false
    strategy: node-first
  uuid: b156b3ed-fde6-4fdc-af81-1ee919edc4ff
```

JobB

```yaml
- defaultTab: nodes
  description: ''
  executionEnabled: true
  id: 4c46c795-20c9-47a8-aa2e-e72f183b150f
  loglevel: INFO
  name: JobB
  nodeFilterEditable: false
  plugins:
    ExecutionLifecycle: null
  scheduleEnabled: true
  sequence:
    commands:
    - exec: whoami
    keepgoing: false
    strategy: node-first
  uuid: 4c46c795-20c9-47a8-aa2e-e72f183b150f
```

JobC (runs every day at 9.00 AM, no matter the JobA execution).

```yaml
- defaultTab: nodes
  description: ''
  executionEnabled: true
  id: ce45c4d1-1350-407b-8001-2d90daf49eaa
  loglevel: INFO
  name: JobC
  nodeFilterEditable: false
  plugins:
    ExecutionLifecycle: null
  schedule:
    month: '*'
    time:
      hour: '09'
      minute: '00'
      seconds: '0'
    weekday:
      day: '*'
    year: '*'
  scheduleEnabled: true
  sequence:
    commands:
    - exec: whoami
    keepgoing: false
    strategy: node-first
  uuid: ce45c4d1-1350-407b-8001-2d90daf49eaa
```

ParentJob (all the behavior logic is inside a bash script, needs [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) tool to work)

```yaml
- defaultTab: nodes
  description: ''
  executionEnabled: true
  id: 6e67020c-7293-4674-8d56-5db811ae5745
  loglevel: INFO
  name: ParentJob
  nodeFilterEditable: false
  plugins:
    ExecutionLifecycle: null
  scheduleEnabled: true
  sequence:
    commands:
    - description: A friendly starting message
      exec: echo "starting..."
    - description: Execute JobA and Get the Status
      fileExtension: .sh
      interpreterArgsQuoted: false
      plugins:
        LogFilter:
        - config:
            invalidKeyPattern: \s|\$|\{|\}|\\
            logData: 'true'
            regex: ^(job_a_exec_id)\s*=\s*(.+)$
          type: key-value-data
      script: "# execute JobA\nexec_id=$(curl -s -X POST \\\n  \"http://localhost:4440/api/41/job/b156b3ed-fde6-4fdc-af81-1ee919edc4ff/run\"\
        \ \\\n  --header \"Accept: application/json\" \\\n  --header \"X-Rundeck-Auth-Token:\
        \ 45hNfblPiF6C1l9CfJeG37l08oAgs0Gd\" | jq .id)\n  \necho \"job_a_exec_id=$exec_id\""
      scriptInterpreter: /bin/bash
    - description: Time to execute the Job
      exec: sleep 2
    - description: 'Get the execution Status '
      fileExtension: .sh
      interpreterArgsQuoted: false
      plugins:
        LogFilter:
        - config:
            invalidKeyPattern: \s|\$|\{|\}|\\
            logData: 'false'
            regex: ^(job_a_exec_status)\s*=\s*(.+)$
          type: key-value-data
      script: "exec_status=$(curl -s -X GET \\\n  'http://localhost:4440/api/41/execution/@data.job_a_exec_id@'\
        \ \\\n  --header 'Accept: application/json' \\\n  --header 'X-Rundeck-Auth-Token:\
        \ 45hNfblPiF6C1l9CfJeG37l08oAgs0Gd' | jq -r .status)\n  \necho \"job_a_exec_status=$exec_status\""
      scriptInterpreter: /bin/bash
    - description: 'Run JobB and JobC pararelly, depending on JobA Execution Status'
      fileExtension: .sh
      interpreterArgsQuoted: false
      script: "# Now execute JobB and JobC depending on the JobA final status (dependency)\n\
        \nif [ @data.job_a_exec_status@ = \"succeeded\" ]; then\n  echo \"Job A execition\
        \ is OK, running JobB and JobC pararelly...\"\n \n  # JobB \n  curl -X POST\
        \ \\\n  \"http://localhost:4440/api/41/job/4c46c795-20c9-47a8-aa2e-e72f183b150f/run\"\
        \ \\\n  --header \"Accept: application/json\" \\\n  --header \"X-Rundeck-Auth-Token:\
        \ 45hNfblPiF6C1l9CfJeG37l08oAgs0Gd\" &\n  \n  # JobC\n  curl -X POST \\\n\
        \  \"http://localhost:4440/api/41/job/ce45c4d1-1350-407b-8001-2d90daf49eaa/run\"\
        \ \\\n  --header \"Accept: application/json\" \\\n  --header \"X-Rundeck-Auth-Token:\
        \ 45hNfblPiF6C1l9CfJeG37l08oAgs0Gd\" &\nelse\n  echo \"Job A has failed, dependencey\
        \ failed\"\nfi"
      scriptInterpreter: /bin/bash
    - description: A friendly ending message
      exec: echo "done."
    keepgoing: false
    strategy: node-first
  uuid: 6e67020c-7293-4674-8d56-5db811ae5745
```

Parent Job's JobB/JobC launching script:

```bash
# Now execute JobB and JobC depending on the JobA final status (dependency)

if [ @data.job_a_exec_status@ = "succeeded" ]; then
  echo "Job A execition is OK, running JobB and JobC pararelly..."
 
  # JobB 
  curl -X POST \
  "http://localhost:4440/api/41/job/4c46c795-20c9-47a8-aa2e-e72f183b150f/run" \
  --header "Accept: application/json" \
  --header "X-Rundeck-Auth-Token: 45hNfblPiF6C1l9CfJeG37l08oAgs0Gd" &
  
  # JobC
  curl -X POST \
  "http://localhost:4440/api/41/job/ce45c4d1-1350-407b-8001-2d90daf49eaa/run" \
  --header "Accept: application/json" \
  --header "X-Rundeck-Auth-Token: 45hNfblPiF6C1l9CfJeG37l08oAgs0Gd" &
else
  echo "Job A has failed, dependencey failed"
fi
```